# How to pass SSIS variables in ODBC SQLCommand expression?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I'm trying to load incremental data from ODBC server to SQL server using common table expression.
When running the query in the Dbeabver application, is executed correctly:

```
with test as
(
    SELECT userid,sum(goldbalance)
    FROM Server.events_live
    where eventTimestamp>=DATE '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL '-100 day'
    group by userid
    order by sum(goldbalance) desc)
)
select * from test
```

when running it from an sql command expression of the ODBC source, it fails due to wrong syntax. It looks as follow:

```
with test as
(
    SELECT userid,sum(goldbalance)
    FROM deltadna.events_live
    where eventTimestamp>=DATE '"+@[User::datestring]+"' + INTERVAL '-100 day'
    group by userid
    order by sum(goldbalance) desc)
)
select * from test"
```

the datestring variable is getting the server date and convert it to string in the format yyyy-mm-dd. I'm usually use this method to pull data from ADO.NET and it works properly.

Is there any other way to pull incremental data from ODBC server using ssis variables?

Comment: I don't know any other way to do this, that's how i usually do this too. Tip: Put the Sql Command Expression in a Variable for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 11):

- **With OLE DB**

Try this code, it works for me with my own tables with SQL Server :

```
SELECT userid,sum(goldbalance) AS SUMGOLD
FROM deltadna.events_live
WHERE eventTimestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -100,CONVERT(DATE,?))
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY SUMGOLD desc
```

You have to click on Parameters in the OLEDB Source Editor to configure what you need. Use the '?' to represent a variable in your query.

[image: Parameters]

If you query if too complicated, stored it in a stored procedure and call it like this:

```
EXEC shema.storedProcedureName ?
```

And map the '?' to your variable @user::DateString

- **With ODBC**

The expressions are outside the data flow in Data Flow Properties.
Select the expression property and add your dynamic query.

[image: ODBC]

And your expression will be

```
"SELECT userid,sum(goldbalance) AS SumGold
FROM deltadna.events_live
where eventTimestamp>=DATE "+@[User::datestring]+" +INTERVAL '-100 day'
group by userid
order by SumGold desc"
```

Comment: Besides OLE DB source, you can't use the Parameters when pulling data- only with an expression for SQLCommand. This is where I used my SSIS variable datestring.

Comment: If you can use only ODBC this is the only way to use expressions, i think that you have a problem with your quotes for your variable. Use mine to test, if doesn't work, add directly ' ' in your string variable expression

Comment: Yeah i tried it as well. I just had to insert an hard-coded date in the datestring variable and my script would replace it's value in every new execution.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: The pictures for the ODBC example were very helpful. I was having a hard time finding the 'Expressions' element in the properties tree.