# SSIS expressions using ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I'm trying to execute a query against an ODBC source using an Execute SQL Task. This is my statement:

```
"select * from RoomType where zz__Timestamp_Modification_UTC__lcm >=  TIMESTAMP '" +@[User::LastJobRunDateTimeUtc]+ "'"
```

in expression builder when I press "Evaluate Expression" button I get this error:

[image: error message]

I've tried various escape characters but nothing is working. I found a post or two on this like this one. From what I can see I'm doing the same thing.
 [How to pass SSIS variables in ODBC SQLCommand expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032225/how-to-pass-ssis-variables-in-odbc-sqlcommand-expression)

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you state your sql query working in database ?

Answer (score 1):

My variable `@[User::LastJobRunDateTimeUtc]` was of type DateTime and apparently expression builder does not like that when using + to combine strings with variables other than string so I cast `@[User::LastJobRunDateTimeUtc]` to a string and it worked.

```
(DT_WSTR,50)@[User::LastJobRunDateTimeUtc]
```